# Latex table multirow problem

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm trying to draw a table where the 3rd column (Average diameter(mm)) spans 3 rows. However, after using multirow, I see that the border on the right is incomplete.

```
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
        \hline
        \textbf{Reading \#} & \textbf{Diameter (mm)} & \textbf{Average Diameter (mm)} \\
        \hline
        1 & 0.7 & \multirow{3}{*}{0.7} \\ 2 & 0.7 \\ 3 & 0.7 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

However, the right border of the table is incomplete. [image]

How do I fix the right border?

Comment: Also related: [Table border is not complete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208270/table-border-is-not-complete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it, I just needed to add an ampersand after each row. Modified code:

```
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Reading \#} & \textbf{Diameter (mm)} & \textbf{Average Diameter (mm)} \\
    \hline
    1 & 0.7 & \multirow{3}{*}{0.7} \\ 2 & 0.7 & \\ 3 & 0.7 &\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a `multirow` problem. It's just because you've declared three columns but use only two in the last two rows. You should always use as much columns as you've declared, even if you are using `multirow` to span rows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Reading \#} & \textbf{Diameter (mm)} & \textbf{Average Diameter (mm)} \\
  \hline
  1 & 0.7 & \multirow{3}{*}{0.7} \\ 
  2 & 0.7 & \\ <-- empty cell added
  3 & 0.7 & \\ <-- empty cell added
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See also [Werner's answer to: Problem with multirow and table cell borders](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58165/9057).